# How do i better define an area to detect a dragged and dropped node?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground

I'm trying to expand on a drag and drop example i've studied from [Drag and drop example](https://blog.lukasjoswiak.com/drag-and-drop-sprites-in-spritekit/) by adding a spot where I can detect a dropped node.

From my attempt at detecting the dropped node, I understand that dropping a node and expecting it to precisely hit a predefined location is difficult.

How do I defined a location or like a rectangle that is larger to detect the dropped node?

```
//: A SpriteKit based Playground

import PlaygroundSupport
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
private var currentNode: SKNode?

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let node = SKSpriteNode(
            color: .red,
            size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        )
        node.name = "draggable"
        self.addChild(node)

        let blueNode = SKSpriteNode(
            color: .blue,
            size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        )
        blueNode.name = "draggable"
        self.addChild(blueNode)

        let greenNode = SKSpriteNode(
            color: .green,
            size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        )
        greenNode.name = "droppable"
        greenNode.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        self.addChild(greenNode)

    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)

            let touchedNodes = self.nodes(at: location)
            for node in touchedNodes.reversed() {
                if node.name == "draggable" {
                    self.currentNode = node
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @objc static override var supportsSecureCoding: Bool {
        // SKNode conforms to NSSecureCoding, so any subclass going
        // through the decoding process must support secure coding
        get {
            return true
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first, let node = self.currentNode {
            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            node.position = touchLocation
        }

    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        print(self.currentNode!.position);

        if self.currentNode!.position == CGPoint(x:100,y:100) {
            let yellowNode = SKSpriteNode(
                color: .yellow,
                size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
            )
            yellowNode.name = "droppable"
            yellowNode.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
            self.addChild(yellowNode)
        }
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.currentNode = nil
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}

// Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
let sceneView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x:0 , y:0, width: 640, height: 480))
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
    // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

    // Present the scene
    sceneView.presentScene(scene)
}

PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = sceneView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are asking for advice in your `touchesEnded(...)` function.

You are right: Checking for a precise location as you do in

```
if self.currentNode!.position == CGPoint(x:100,y:100) {}
```

won't bring you too far. It is very hard to manually hit a specific point on screen.

You could for example specify your target area with a `CGRect` and then check if the location of the touch lies within the rectangle.

```
let targetRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
guard let node = self.currentNode else {return} // Just to avoid forced unwrapping
if targetRect.contains(node.position) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I noticed that there seems to be a difference between CGRect and SKSpriteNode that I'm not understanding. IE when I use:  let targetRect = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200) versus         let greenNode = SKSpriteNode(
            color: .green,
            size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
        )
        
        greenNode.name = "droppable"
        greenNode.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100) playing around seems to show that the CGRect positioning is different to SKSpriteNode. Can you help me understand this please?

Comment: This happens, because CGrect and SKSpriteNode use different coordinate systems. The (x,y) pair for a CGRect specifies its origin, ie the top left corner. The position attribute of a SKSpriteNode specifies its center.